# How to retrieve database to popup modal jquery after click?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am new with jquery, and i am looking for retrieve from the database and display it in a popup modal after click on button.
The main scenario i am looking for is to display all messages that specific user sent to another users. and each button will have the message title. after i click on a button, a modal popup will showen and the message content will be in it.
What i am getting right now: buttons show with the messages title, and the content is hidden.

.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function openMessageContent(obj) {
        var contentMessage = obj.innerHTML;
        $("#showContent").dialog("option", "title", contentMessage);
        initializeMap(contentMessage);
        $("#showContent").dialog("open");
    }
    $(function () {
        $("#showContent").dialog({
            height: 480,
            width: 450,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "fade",
                duration: 500
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "fade",
                duration: 500
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="IncomeMessages">
    <div class="IncomeMessages_Header">Income Messages</div>
    <div id="IncomeMessagesPH" class="IncomeMessagesPH" runat="server"></div>
</div>

<div class="SentMessages">
    <div class="SentMessages_Header">Sent Messages</div>
    <div id="SentMessagesPH" class="SentMessagesPH" runat="server"></div>
</div>

<div id="showContent" runat="server">
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Private_User_Social_MessageList : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DBservices DBS = new DBservices();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<TblMessage> ListSMessages = DBS.getSentMessages(User.Identity.Name.ToString());
        int countMessages = 0;
        foreach (TblMessage MESIndex in ListSMessages)
        {
            string _SentMessage = MES_output(MESIndex);

            AjaxControlToolkit.HoverExtender TempHover = new AjaxControlToolkit.HoverExtender();
            TempHover.TargetControlID = MESIndex.SendEmail;
            TempHover.ID = MESIndex.Mnum.ToString();

            Label MessContent = new Label();
            MessContent.Text = MESIndex.Content;

            Button tempApprove = new Button();
            tempApprove.Text = MESIndex.Subject;
            tempApprove.CssClass = "ApproveBTN";

            SentMessagesPH.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div style='height:32px'>"));
            SentMessagesPH.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div id='Message" + countMessages + "' style='height:32px;visibility:hidden;display:none'>"));
            SentMessagesPH.Controls.Add(MessContent);
            SentMessagesPH.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
            SentMessagesPH.Controls.Add(tempApprove);
            SentMessagesPH.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));

            string PresentContentDIV = "<div id='MESIContent'>";
            LiteralControl PresentContent = new LiteralControl(PresentContentDIV);
            PresentContentDIV = "<a 'href='#' onclick='openMessageContent(MessContent); return false;'>";
            PresentContentDIV += "</a>";
            PresentContentDIV += "<p> " + MessContent.Text + " </p>";
            PresentContentDIV += "</div>";
            PresentContent = new LiteralControl(PresentContentDIV);
            showContent.Controls.Add(PresentContent);

            countMessages++;
        }
    }

    protected string MES_output(TblMessage _tempMES)
    {
        string ans = _tempMES.SendEmail;
        return ans;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The message need to be showed when the page reload? I think the best way to do your main scenario is work with ajax calling some webmethods that retrieving json. This way you wont reload all page.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

look this example

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Retrieve-data-from-Database-and-display-on-page-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx